# Spring 2.5.1 and Xfire 1.2.6 - NoSuchMethodError: <init>

Tags: java, web-services, spring, weblogic, xfire

Trying to integrate Spring 2.5.5 with Xfire 1.2.6, I'm attempting to inject one of my beans into my service but it's failing on initialisation with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:420)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:357)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:763)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I get this as soon as I send my first request to the service via SoapUI. I've been googling and struggling for days with this now and I'd love some help :)

Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.4"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/datasourceContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:org/codehaus/xfire/spring/xfire.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.moo.app.util.appWSEnvLifeCycleListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>xfire</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>detail</param-name>
            <param-value>3</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.moo.app.dashboard.servlet.LogFileServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>xfire</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogFile</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.zip</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zip</extension>
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Struts Tag Library Descriptors -->
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-bean</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-html</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-logic</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-nested</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/tags/struts-tiles</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/struts-tiles.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

and my applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

 <bean id="app.TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="app.TxProxyTemplate"
  class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
  abstract="true">
  <property name="transactionManager" ref="app.TransactionManager" />
  <property name="transactionAttributes">
   <props>
    <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
    <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS</prop>
    <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS</prop>
    <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="app.BaseappDAO" class="com.moo.app.app.data.BaseappDAO" abstract="true">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="app.MembershipDetailsDAO" class="com.moo.app.app.data.MembershipDetailsDAOImpl"
  parent="app.BaseappDAO">
 </bean>

 <bean id="app.MembershipDetails" class="com.moo.app.app.data.MembershipDetailsServiceImpl">
  <property name="membershipDetailsDAO" ref="app.MembershipDetailsDAO" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="app.appService" class="com.moo.app.app">
     <property name="membershipDetailsService" ref="app.MembershipDetails" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

and finally, my xfire-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="urlMap">
   <map>
    <entry key="/services/app/">
     <ref bean="app.appService"/>
    </entry>
   </map>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <!-- Declare a parent bean with all properties common to both services -->
 <bean id="echo" class="org.codehaus.xfire.spring.remoting.XFireExporter">
  <property name="serviceFactory">
   <ref bean="xfire.serviceFactory"/>
  </property>
  <property name="xfire">
   <ref bean="xfire"/>
  </property>
  <property name="serviceBean">
   <ref bean="app.appService"/>
  </property>
  <property name="serviceClass">
   <value>com.moo.app.app.appService</value>
  </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

No idea why this is occuring. The JARs I'm using are as follows:

- activation-1.1.jar
- app-SNAPSHOT.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-codec-1.3.jar
- commons-collections.jar
- commons-digester.jar
- commons-fileupload.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar
- commons-lang.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.0.jar
- commons-validator.jar
- jaxen-1.1-beta-9.jar
- jaxws-api-2.0.jar
- jdom-1.0.jar
- jsr173_api-1.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.12.jar
- ojdbc14.jar
- saaj-api-1.3.jar
- saaj-impl-1.3.jar
- spring-webmvc-1.2.6.jar
- spring.2.5.1.jar
- struts-legacy.jar
- struts.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
- wstx-asl-3.2.0.jar
- xbean-spring-2.8.jar
- xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-annotations-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-core-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-java5-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-jaxws-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-jsr181-api-1.0-M1.jar
- xfire-spring-1.2.6.jar
- XmlSchema-1.1.jar

I'm deploying this on Weblogic 8.2 as a WAR file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have version mismatch in your spring jars - the spring is 2.5.1 and the spring web mvc is the (rather old) 1.2.6. Why not move both of them to the latest 2.5.6.SEC01?

Comment: spring-webmvc-1.2.6.jar is the only one I could find for Spring WebMVC. I got it via repo1.maven.org/maven2. Any ideas where I could get that version (2.5.6) for both?

Comment: Even if 1.2.6 was the only version you could find, that's no reason to use it anyway, it's clearly not going to work with the 2.5.1 core.

Comment: Scrap that, found the JARs locally. Trying with the updated JARs